# angular ui-router resolve if params set

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like secure my route access by redirect the user if no params send.
to prevent direct url access.
I can do that in my controller but i have in my resolve some web service call.
the goal is to not call the resolve if the params isn't present.
Here my state :

```
.state('parent.step2', {
    url: '/step2',
    templateUrl: 'app/template/step2.html',
    controller: 'Step2Controller',
    controllerAs: 'step2',
    params: {name: null},
    data : {
        step: 2
    },
    resolve: {
        data1: ['Data1', function(Data1) {
            return Data1.query().$promise;
        }],
        data2: ['Data2', '$stateParams', function(Data2, $stateParams) {
            return Data2.query({name: $stateParams.name}).$promise;
        }],
        data3: ['Data3', function(Data3) {
            return Data3.query().$promise;
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Just add a simple `if` statement in `data2` resolve to check if `$stateParams` contains the required parameters or not, and if not, return a rejection using `$q.reject()` (add `$q` service to the function injection)

Comment: Why don't you do a interceptor service for all response error (code 401) that redirect to Login page maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have put a listener on the `$stateChangeStart` event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ((!toState.data.step) && ($state.current.name === 'parent.step2')) {
        $state.go('error');
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thank, i just add to add
event.preventDefault();
before the redirection and change "$state.current.name" by "toState.name"